# Code is not executed when filtering the array to display the desired value

Tags: javascript

I want to show the name and price of foods whose price is higher than 10 in the console, but I will encounter an error.

```js
let menu = [
    { id: 1, name: "Soda", price: 3.12, size: "4oz", type: "Drink" },
    { id: 2, name: "Beer", price: 6.50, size: "8oz", type: "Drink" },
    { id: 3, name: "Margarita", price: 12.99, size: "12oz", type: "Drink" },
    { id: 4, name: "Pizza", price: 25.10, size: "60oz", type: "Food" },
    { id: 5, name: "Kebab", price: 31.48, size: "42oz", type: "Food" },
    { id: 6, name: "Berger", price: 23.83, size: "99oz", type: "Food" },
];
const maxPriceFood = () => {
    for (let value of menu) {
        for (let value of menu.price)
            if (value > 10 && type === "Food") {
                return `name food : ${menu.name} price food : ${menu.price}`
            }
    }
};

console.log(maxPriceFood());
```

Comment: 1. Numbers aren't iterable (`for (let value of menu.price)`). 2. You're not doing anything with your outer `value` value (`for (let value of menu)`). 3. This isn't a filtering operation, it's a find operation that will return exactly one result. 4. You have an undeclared variable (`type`).

Comment: Perhaps you meant something [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/tjcrowder/pLturnsd/), but it's hard to say from the question as it stands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

menu.price is not iterable (unlike menu which is an array).

You can refactor the method to work like this:

```
for (let menuItem of menu) {
    if (menuItem.price > 10 && menuItem.type === "Food") {
        return `name food : ${menuItem.name} price food : ${menuItem.price}`
    }
}
```

Another simpler option is to use the array built in functions for that: (filter and forEach).

```
const maxPriceFood = () => menu.filter(menuItem => menuItem.price > 10 && 
menuItem.type === "Food").forEach(x => console.log(`name food : ${x.name} price food : ${x.price}`));

maxPriceFood();
//"name food : Pizza price food : 25.1"
//"name food : Kebab price food : 31.48"
//"name food : Berger price food : 23.83"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to get and show food items with a price over 10:

```js
let menu = [
    { id: 1, name: "Soda", price: 3.12, size: "4oz", type: "Drink" },
    { id: 2, name: "Beer", price: 6.50, size: "8oz", type: "Drink" },
    { id: 3, name: "Margarita", price: 12.99, size: "12oz", type: "Drink" },
    { id: 4, name: "Pizza", price: 25.10, size: "60oz", type: "Food" },
    { id: 5, name: "Kebab", price: 31.48, size: "42oz", type: "Food" },
    { id: 6, name: "Berger", price: 23.83, size: "99oz", type: "Food" },
];
const maxPriceFood = () => {
    // Get items with a price over 10
    const itemsOver10 = menu.filter(item => item.price > 10 && item.type === "Food");
    return itemsOver10.map(item =>  `name food : ${item.name} price food : ${item.price}`);
};

console.log(maxPriceFood());
```

Answer (score 0):

You're doing an extra loop.
In my example, the first loop declares in the variable "entry" each one of the instances in the list, and compares their price.

Also, if you do a return, you exit the function without checking the rest of the prices.

```js
let menu = [
    { id: 1, name: "Soda", price: 3.12, size: "4oz", type: "Drink" },
    { id: 2, name: "Beer", price: 6.50, size: "8oz", type: "Drink" },
    { id: 3, name: "Margarita", price: 12.99, size: "12oz", type: "Drink" },
    { id: 4, name: "Pizza", price: 25.10, size: "60oz", type: "Food" },
    { id: 5, name: "Kebab", price: 31.48, size: "42oz", type: "Food" },
    { id: 6, name: "Berger", price: 23.83, size: "99oz", type: "Food" },
];
const maxPriceFood = () => {
    let maxPrices = [];
    for (let entry of menu) {
      if (entry.price > 10 && entry.type === "Food") {
          maxPrices.push(`name food : ${entry.name} price food : ${entry.price}`);
      }
    }
    return maxPrices;
};

console.log(maxPriceFood());
```